Leslie Matrices and Logarithms with matrix base
Apologies for poor formatting this is my first time posting on here and as such do not know how to format correctly.

When you are given a Leslie Matrix that is modelling rats population growth and you want to figure out at what cycle does the population reach a certain number:
The equation can be modelled as $P_{0}L^{x} S = \left[a\right]$.
$P_{0}$ is our initial distribution matrix = $\left[ 15, 9, 13, 5, 0, 0 \right]$.
$L$ has birthrates of $\left[0,
.3,\ .8,\ .7,\ .4,\ 0 \right]$ and survival rates
of $\left[.6,\ .9,\ .9,\ .8,\ .6,\ 0\right]$
$S$ is a column matrix of six $1$'s
$\left[a\right]$ is the population to which we want to find the cycles needed: For this problem
I have been using $150$ rats.
I am unsure of how to find the amount of cycles needed to reach $150$ rats: I thought you could divide both sides by $P_{0}$ and then $S$ to have $L^{x} = \left[150\right]/\left(P_{0}S\right)$.
The matrix rules still apply here as $P_{0}$ is $1 \times 6$ and $S$ is $6 \times 1$.
Continuing this logic I thought you would just take the logarithm of both sides to find $x$  resulting in
$$
\operatorname{Log}_{L}\left(\left[150\right]/\left(P_{0}S\right)\right) = x
$$
but my calculator could not do this, and I suspect because mathematically you cannot.
My google searches have brought back needing to find Eigenvalues and Jordan Canonical forms. I do not quite know what either of these are, but using an online calculator found that the characteristic polynomial of the Leslie Matrix is
$$
\lambda^{6} - 0.18\lambda^{4} - 0.432\lambda^{3} - 0.3402\lambda^{2} - 0.15552\lambda
$$
resulting in eigenvalues of $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda = 1.03043$ ( according to desmos ).

But from here I am stuck:

What do I do next ?.
Is this solvable ?.
Do I just have to guess and check to find $x$ ?.


https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10164 for formatting.  Your statement "I thought you could divide both sides by $P_0$ and then $S$ to have $L^x = [150]/(P_0 * S)$. The matrix rules still apply here as P0 is 1×6 and S is 6×1"  does not make sense.   The gating item is going to be that at least one semester of linear algebra is a pre-req here.
